# the object reference is able to access the private data members direcly

Tags: java

```
public class College{ 
  int year; 
  String name; 
  College(int year,String name){ 
        year=year; 
        name=name; 
  } 

  public static void main(String[] args) { 
        College first=new College(1998,"BITS"); 
        System.out.println("The year is:"+first.year); 
        System.out.println("The name is:"+first.name); 
  } 
}
```

My output is:
the year is `0`
the name is `null`

how is this? 
According to me, the object first cannot access the private data members directly.

Answer (score 6):

This happens because you're shadowing `year` and `name` fields inside your constructor.

Use either:

```
  College(int year,String name){ 
        this.year=year; 
        this.name=name; 
  }
```

or:

```
  College(int y,String n){ 
        year=y; 
        name=n; 
  }
```

I prefer the first option.

BTW, the fields **aren't private** as you didn't declare them as one and default is `package`.
Even if you'd set them as private, static methods that belong to a class can see private member variables.

Comment: thanx whoAmI, whoever you are :)

Answer (score 5):

By declaring this:

```
year=year; 
name=name;
```

...you are **shadowing** your variables.

There is scope associated with your variables, and currently, the scope of both `year` and `name` is within the constructor.  You're basically assigning it on top of itself.

You have a few options:

- Use the `this` operator - `this.year = year;`
- Rename the incoming variable names by prepending them with something:

  ```
  College (int theYear, String theName) {
      year = theYear;
      name = theName;
  }
  ```

Furthermore, there aren't any private fields within this class.  They're all set up to be package-private, which is no visibility modifier at all.

If you had specified the fields `year` and `name` with the `private` modifier, then you'd be right; you'd have to use a getter to retrieve the variable values.

Comment: static methods that belong to a class can see private member variables.  This is why he can access them in `main`.

Comment: It's an object.  He's pulling the values directly from the object.  It's no different than calling `getYear()`.  That doesn't have to be declared as `static`.  Also, there *aren't* any private fields.  They're all package-private.

Comment: @Steve, Those variables are not private , In java variable have default access specifier as package.

Comment: @AlpeshGediya, but the answer states that if they *were* `private` then a getter would be required.  This is not the case.

Answer (score 1):

You must use

```
this.year = year 
this.name = name
```

in constructor 
this will solve the problem :)

Answer (score 1):

**In your question you mentioned, for below variables that they are private data members but that is not correct for your declaration.**

```
   int year;  // default access specifier (for variable) is package not private  
   String name; /// default access specifier (for variable) is package not private
```

The default visibility is known as “package” (though you can't use this keyword), which means the field will be accessible from inside the same package to which the class belongs.
[See more information here.](http://xahlee.info/java-a-day/access_specifiers.html)

You are shadowing variables in your code so you can fix them using below code

```
 College(int year,String name){ 
        this.year=year; 
        this.name=name; 
  }
```